# Externally linked .css file is not working with html5 code

Tags: html, css

I have following html file in my visual studio 2013 project

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="css/my.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile- 1.4.2.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
    #loginBody {
        color: aqua;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
        //$.support.cors =true,
        //$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

        $('#frmLogin').validate(
            {
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                username: {
                    required: "Please enter your username."
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please enter your password."
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                //$("#frmLogin").submit(function (event) {
                //event.preventDefault();
                var credentials = { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "api/auth", // this url is just a placeholder
                    cache: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data,status,jqxhr)
                    {
                        //validate the response here, set variables... whatever needed
                        //and if credentials are valid, forward to the next page
                        if (data.status == "success")
                        {
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                            localStorage.setItem("acccessToken", obj.accessToken);
                            alert(obj.accessToken);
                            $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer ("change", "Authorization.html", { role: "page" });
                            //window.location.href = "http://www.jqueryvalidation.org";
                        }
                        else if(data.status== "error")
                        {
                            alert("Authentication Invalid.Please try again!");
                            return false;
                        }
                        //or show an error message
                    },
                    error: function (jqxhr, status, errorMsg)
                    {
                        // server couldn't be reached or other error 
                        alert("jqXHR Status : " + jqxhr.status + " Status: " + status + " Error: " + errorMsg);
                    }
                }, "json");
                return false;
            }//);
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
label.error
{
color: red;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.4;
margin-top: 0.5em;
width: 100%;
float: none;
}

 @media screen and (orientation: portrait){
label.error { margin-left: 0; display: block; }
 }

@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
label.error { display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; }
}
em { color: red; font-weight: bold; padding-right: .25em; }
</style>
</head>
<body id="loginBody">
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1> Intergraph </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="frmLogin" method="post" action="api/auth" data-ajax="false">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">
                        <em>* </em> Username:
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="username"
                           name="username" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="password">
                        <em>* </em>Password:
                    </label>
                    <input type="password" id="password"
                           name="password" />
                </div>

                <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <button class="btnLogin" type="submit" id="loginBtn"
                            data-theme="a">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--<div data-role="page" id="success" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
             <h1>Thank You!!!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>-->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is code inside my my.css file

```
#loginBody
{
    background: url('../images/my-generic-curved-background.png') no-repeat fixed center bottom;
background-size:390px 320px; color:blue;
}

#loginContent
{
   text-align:center;
   margin-top:210px;
   color:aquamarine;
}
```

Now the weird thing is this file is not read or  not loaded (I'm not sure and even I don't know how to ascertain that) but when I replace  #loginBody selector with * (all) I can see the image in the background of the page is displayed and also blue color in the portion of the page which is not covered by the image (so may be my.css file is getting loaded on the run , I would suppose). So precisely what I mean is that css rules are getting applied on for * (all) selector and other selectors too but not for #loginBody selector, why is that?

All ideas and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It could be that some CSS rule in the jQuery mobile CSS files is overriding your own styles, i.e. with an "!important". Try commenting out the other CSS files' <link> tags to check this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the base styles setup by JQM. The `.ui-overlay-a` class sets colours that you aren't overriding and you've also placed your `my.css` before any JQM includes. To override, your `my.css` must be last in the link includes and you need to use `!important`.

I would suggest heading to the bottom of the official themes page and look through the overrides for each section. They don't provide information on background images but it will show you what the capabilities are out-of-the-box.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc2/docs/api/themes.html

> The data-theme attribute can be applied to the header and footer
>   containers to apply any of the lettered theme color swatches. While
>   the data-theme attribute could be added to the content container, we
>   recommend adding it instead to div or container that has been assigned
>   the data-role="page" attribute to ensure that the background color is
>   applied to the full page.

I'd also suggest using developer tools to inspect the elements and how JQM is settings styles. In Chrome/FF you right click on an element and select `Inspect Element`.

Comment: I tried it both way, first by  putting !important when using #loginBody as a selector and then leaving it as such and commenting out jmq css file, still the same old situation.